# Как сложить datetime.time и datetime.timedelta

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему?

Функция генератор принимает два аргумента (кортежи с 3 целыми числами) и должна возвращать первичное время time_start и на каждой следующей итерации возвращать предыдущий результат +1 секунда. При этом час окончания может быть меньше от начального.

Функцию я сделал:

```
import datetime
from datetime import time


def time_range(time_start: tuple, time_end: tuple) -> tuple:
    start = time(time_start[0], time_start[1], time_start[2])
    end = time(time_end[0], time_end[1], time_end[2])
    step = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)

    while start <= end:
        new_result = start + step
        yield new_result


t_range = time_range(time_start=(10, 0, 0), time_end=(10, 0, 3))
print(next(t_range))  # == (10, 0, 0)
print(next(t_range))  # == (10, 0, 1)
print(next(t_range))  # == (10, 0, 2)
```

Но есть две проблемы, которые не могу решить:

1. Выдает ошибку и не складывает datetime.time и datetime.timedelta (в документации почитал, но так и не понял как можно решить эту проблему).
2. Не могу сообразить как возвращать первичное время time_start, а уже после этого возвращать время + 1 секунда?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time

Answer (score 2):

по первому сделаем, как написано по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448592/how-to-add-delta-to-python-datetime-time)

по второму вопросу: поменяйте местами yield и увеличение текущего времени

```
def time_range(time_start: tuple, time_end: tuple) -> tuple:
    start = time(time_start[0], time_start[1], time_start[2])
    end = time(time_end[0], time_end[1], time_end[2])
    step = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)

    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1, 1, 1), start) + step).time()


t_range = time_range(time_start=(10, 0, 0), time_end=(10, 0, 3))
print(next(t_range))  # == (10, 0, 0)
print(next(t_range))  # == (10, 0, 1)
print(next(t_range))  # == (10, 0, 2)
```

выводит

```
10:00:00
10:00:01
10:00:02
```

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению нужно возврашать не время а кортеж вот такие (10, 0, 0) (10, 0, 1) (10, 0, 2)

Comment: Так возьмите часы, минуты и секунды из времени

Comment: С этим разобрался, но все равно не работает когда на вход даю time_start = (23, 59, 58), time_end = (0, 0, 7)
результат должен быть (23, 59, 58), (23, 59, 59), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), ..., у меня выбивает ошибку StopIteration

Comment: да, понятно, потому что start становится больше end. в этом случае придется полностью работать с datetime и задавать время окончания в пределах следующих суток. тогда будет работать